# insert a record or if exist then update in mysql doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

i want that if a record doesnt exist i add it otherwise update it... but it doesnt work, whats the wrong with this code:

```
<?php
      $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
      $user_email="user_email";
      $last_stage=$_POST['last_stage'];
      $score=$_POST['score'];
      $note=$_POST['note'];

      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ferfer","Drfrj","ferfw");
      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user_email FROM rating WHERE user_email='".$user_email."'");
      $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if ($num_rows > 0) {
        //echo "exist";
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rating SET user_id=".$user_id.", user_email='".$user_email."', last_stage=".$last_stage.", score=".$score.", note='".$note."'  WHERE user_email='".$user_email."'";
        mysqli_close($con);
      }else{
        //echo "does not exist";
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO rating(user_id, user_email, last_stage, score, note)VALUES (".$user_id.",'".$user_email."',".$last_stage.",".$score.",'".$note."') ");          
        mysqli_close($con);
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work? Do you get any error?

Comment: what do u mean?? doesn't work mean doesn't update or doesn't insert?

Comment: Why you doing multiple queries? Use INSERT OR ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE like this `INSERT INTO tblclientoptions (ClientID,LateTarget) VALUES ($lid,$latetarget) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LateTarget=$latetarget`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually do it in a single query since `MySQL` has implemented [**INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) which basically `INSERT`s a record if it does not exists otherwise `UPDATE`s it.

The first thing you need to do is to add a `UNIQUE` column on the table. In your example I see that `user_email` is the column you are searching for existence. If this is not unique, you need to alter the table for `UNIQUE` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE rating ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE(user_email)
```

after it has been implement, build a query like this,

```
INSERT INTO rating(user_id, user_email, last_stage, score, note)
VALUES($user_id, '$user_email', last_stage, score, '$note')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   user_id = $user_id, 
   last_stage = $last_stage, 
   score = $score, 
   note= '$note'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

```
$user_email="user_email";
```

should be changed to

```
$user_email=$_POST['user_email'];
```

And missing ( simbol, as @Yogesh Suthar said. You should also consider escaping characters in strings, using i.e. mysql_real_escape_string function.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot `)` here

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rating SET user_id=".$user_id.", user_email='".$user_email."', last_stage=".$last_stage.", score=".$score.", note='".$note."'  
WHERE user_email='".$user_email."'");
                                   ^ // here
```

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to use

```
REPLACE INTO `rating` (user_id,user_email,last_stage,score,note)
VALUES(@user_id,@user_email,@last_stage,@score,@note) WHERE user_email=@email
```

use also binding and prepared statements to make it more secure. Your code is very insecure because you have nor escape functions neither casting.

Example of using binding with PHP. $dbh is PDO object.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE INTO `rating` (user_id,user_email,last_stage,score,note)
VALUES(@user_id,@user_email,@last_stage,@score,@note) WHERE user_email=@email");
$stmt->bindParam('@name', (int)$user_id);
$stmt->bindParam('@user_email', $user_email);
$stmt->bindParam('@last_stage', $last_stage);
$stmt->bindParam('@score', $score);
$stmt->bindParam('@note', $note);
```

more on https://www.php.net/pdo

with binding you don't have to escape strings because it goes straight into the database layer without it having to be crudely spliced into the SQL statement.

The MySQL REPLACE statement works like the INSERT statement with the additional rules:

If the record which you want to insert does not exist, the MySQL REPLACE inserts a new record.
If the record which you want to insert already exists, MySQL REPLACE  deletes the old record first and then insert a new record.

Answer (score 0):

`$user_email="user_email";` should be `$user_email=$_POST["user_email"];`